# Reset synchronized VS settings

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

I've synchronized my VS settings over 2 versions of VS and multiple machines.  I'd use the out-of-the-box settings from a fresh VS 2017 install and only synchronize changes I make going-forward.  Is there any way completely reset/delete my existing synchronized settings and start fresh?  I logged-into VS Online but didn't find an option for that.

Answer (score 1):

Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset all settings.

You can also find where your settings file is saved by starting to export or import, then manually delete that file.

Comment: So I should sign-in first, let is sync my old settings, then reset as you've indicated?

Comment: If you're not interested in keeping your settings, it shouldn't matter whether or not it syncs.

Comment: You'd think - but I don't trust VS to get this scenario right.  =)

Comment: Well, maybe don't do my answer. I may have misunderstood your question. I thought you didn't care to keep your customized settings.

Comment: You are right - I don't care to keep my customized settings in the VS cloud.  Anyways, I think you're suggestion will work.